# Is there any way to save Blob array to a txt file and after read and play as Video

Tags: javascript, canvas, video-streaming

I am working with MediaRecoder for save canvas actions as Video.(format is not matter)

```
var recordedBlobs =[];
var stream = canvas.captureStream();
var mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream, options);
```

captureStream function collecting my canvases edited data, and I am saving this data with this function.

```
 function handleDataAvailable(event) {
            if (event.data && event.data.size > 0) {
                recordedBlobs.push(event.data);
            }
        }
```

When stop to record stream I am calling this function for play my recordedBlobs as video.

```
function handleStop(event) {
            debugger;
            console.log('Recorder stopped: ', event);
            const superBuffer = new Blob(recordedBlobs, { type:'video/webm'});
            video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(superBuffer);
        }
```

Its working fine. Videoplayer is starting to play my canvas data as video.
But i want to record this values to a txt file or something like that.The reason is this canvas actions may take 1 hour and video size may be 1 GB and more then this. My goal is read this txt in another page and play this data as video but I dont know how can i do this.

What is the best way for me to save this datas?

Answer (score 0):

You are pretty much there , just add

```
const superBuffer = new Blob(recordedBlobs, { type:'video/webm'});
let objUrl = window.URL.createObjectURL(superBuffer);
let anchor = document.createElement('a');
anchor.href = objUrl;
anchor.setAttribute('download', 'YourFileName.txt');
anchor.click();
```

Comment: Thank you Pranoy.  I was download this file as same as you before. But I dont know how can I play this txt as video after read it. Do you have any idea ?